# How to place two horizontal lines one by one with different sizes aligned centered in same div?

Tags: html, css

How can i  align the two different sizes lines one by one horizontally with no space between them?

Like
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkFFa.png) i want no space between the lines means the APP downloads exactly after 5M

I tried with the following:

```css
.text
{
  color:white;
}
.big
{
  font-size:5em;
}
.small
{
  font-size:2em;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <span class="big">52M</span>
  <span class="small">App Downloads</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use 'flex-box' and change the 'line-height' value of the span elements. It's a possible solution.

[Example](http://codepen.io/martacg/pen/AXRLQE)

```
.text
{
  width:20%;
  height:20%;
  padding:5%;
  background:red;
  color:white;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.big
{
  font-size:5em;
  line-height:0.8em;
  margin:auto;
}
.small
{
  font-size:2em;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a break in between them to space them out like so.

```
<style>
.text
{
   color:white;
}

.big
{
    font-size:5em;
}

.small
{
   font-size:2em;
   display:inline-block;
}
</style>

<div class="text">
  <span class="big">52M</span>
    <br>
    <br>
  <span class="small">App Downloads</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using display:block and float left:

```
 .text {
    color:white;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    text-align:center;
  }

span {
   display: block;
   width:100%;
   float:left;
   margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: i want no space between the 5M and APP downloads

Answer (score 0):

Try white-space: nowrap

```
<style>
.text
{
  color:white;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.big
{
  font-size:5em;
}
.small
{
  font-size:2em;
  display:inline-block;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

With text-align: center.

Try this: http://codepen.io/r3npi2/pen/vKmgZG

```
.text
{
  color:white;
  background-color:red;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}
.big
{
  font-size:5em;
  display:block;
}
.small
{
  font-size:2em;
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you *want* them to be underneath each other... the question isn't very clear regarding that.

All you have to do here is change the span elements to block elements, either by CSS or - the reason I'd prefer for simplicity - changing them to divs. Then, give the surrounding div a text-align:center (and a background-color to see the result), and you're done!

```css
.text {
  background-color: #d00;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.big {
  font-size:5em;
}
.small {
  font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <div class="big">52M</div>
  <div class="small">App Downloads</div>
</div>
```